# Parameter is not valid when trying to select item icon

Tags: content-editor

I'm trying to set an icon for an item in `Sitecore 8.2`. When I click the `More Icons` button, I get the error message below.

[image: More Icons]

```
The parameter is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
```

[image: Sitecore error message]

What's strange is that I have this site deployed to another environment and it's working fine there.  It's only giving me this error on my local development machine.  I think it might be a corrupt cached image file that's causing the error, but I don't know how to clear that cache out.

Comment: Clear `/App_Data/MediaCache` for media, also there is an icon cache at `<webroot>/temp/IconCache` - try clearing that too and restart IIS

Comment: I deleted the IconCache folder and the MediaCache folder and that didn't help.  I also deleted the .ZIP files from the /Website/sitecore/shell/Themes/Standard and copied them from the .ZIP file from Sitecore and that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: The error comes from the gdiplus.dll so it's hard to say what's going wrong. I think it may fail to write the bitmap because access rights don't allow it. Since it's local, you could try to set full permissions to everyone on the web root folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a security issue.  It is recreating the IconCache folder and starting to populate it as needed. But I did go ahead and reapplied security and that didn't help.  And I gave "Everyone" full control and that didn't help.  I just copied the IconCache folder and Themes folder from the environment that is working and it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was not in the IconCache folder, but rather the temp folder.  I deleted everything from temp and it fixed the problem.